# Passing a link via viewbag MVC RAZOR &amp appearing

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to pass a link from my controller to my view using viewbag, the link is to be used as the source for an iframe. However & appears so the lnk does not work.

Controller

```
link = "http://example.com/Index?aa=aa&q=bb";
ViewBag.Answer3 = link;
```

View

```
<iframe height="30" id="Audio" src="">

<script>
     function Reveal () {
     var listen = document.getElementById("Audio");
     listen.src = "@ViewBag.Answer3";
     ...
```

However it doesn't work and when I look at the debugger I see this

```
listen.src = "http://example.com/Index?aa=aa&amp;q=bb";
```

Thanks in advance for your help
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor automatically HTML-encodes any string you output.

You can prevent this with `Html.Raw()`.
However, you need to Javascript-encode it instead in case it has quotes.